# WebdriverIO with Playwright

Tags: automation, webdriver-io, playwright

I was wondering if it is possible to combine WebdriverIO with Playwright since Playwright has more extended functionalities than WebdriverIO.

I know both frameworks launch chromium independently. But is there any way where I can use Playwright functions for the browser launched by WebdriverIO?

Comment: What is the use case you need to satisfy in order to do such a thing? WDIO implements the WebDriver protocol, while PlayWright/Puppeteer, only use the ChromeDevTools protocol to manipulate versions of a chromium instance. You either use one hammer, or the other to drive your nail. Hope this help!

Comment: For example, I want to wait until all requests get a response (network idle) when a page is loaded.

Comment: You could possibly use [WDIO ChromeDevTool Service](https://webdriver.io/docs/devtools-service/) to achieve this, or network intercept libraries integrated with your tool. Choose one, or the other. No way around.